Why was Mordechai Certain of רוח והצלה יעמוד if he Created the Danger?
Mordechai was sitting in the palace gate (Esther 2:21). The King had issued a general command - all servants of the king in the palace gate shall bow to Haman (Esther 3:2). Mordechai refused to bow.
The R' Y"S Reggio (3:2) states (my loose translation follows):
https://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Esther/3/2#e0n6


רבינו י״ש ריגייו

(ב-ד) [ב] מה שהיה מרדכי ממאן לכרוע ולהשתחות להמן כמצות המלך אין לו בזה שום התנצלות, כי אם היה מפני היות צלם בבגדו, הנה העקר חסר מן הספר, וכתוב מלא הוא כורעים ומשתחוים להמן לא לצלם. לכן דבר ברור הוא שהאומרים כן בקשו רק להפוך בזכותו כפי האפשר. ואם מפני שהיה קודם לכן עבדו משועבד לו, הנה גם זה דבר שאין לו משענה בדברי הכתוב, מלבד שאין די בטעם הזה לפוטרו מן החוב לשמוע בקול המלך, כי בני ישראל מחוייבים בזמן הגלות לשמור מצות המלך אשר הם תחת ממשלתו, ודינא דמלכותא דינא.
ואם מפני שלא רצה להשתחוות לבן אדם, הנה טעה בהתחסדות, כי דבר זה לא נאסר לנו מן התורה, ואברהם השתחוה לעם הארץ {בראשית כ״ג:ז׳,י״ב}, ויעקב ובני ביתו לעשו {בראשית ל״ג:ג׳-ז׳}, גם בני יעקב ליוסף {בראשית מ״ב:ו׳, מ״ג:כ״ו-כ״ח}, ורות לבועז {רות ב׳:י׳}, ודוד ליהונתן {שמואל א כ׳:מ״א} ולשאול {שמואל א כ״ד:ח׳}, ואביגיל {שמואל א כ״ה:כ״ג,מ״א} ומפיבשת {שמואל ב ט׳:ו׳,ח׳} ואחימעץ לדוד {שמואל ב י״ח:כ״ח} ורבים כמוהם, ולמה זה מרדכי לבדו יתחסד יותר מכולם? ואם תאמר שחשב שלא ישגיח המן עליו כמו שבאמת לא היה משגיח לולי עבדי המלך הולכי רכיל הודיעוהו זאת, למה אם כן לא השתחוה כשראה שהגיע הדבר לאזני המן? ואיך יביא עצמו וכל בית ישראל בסכנה עצומה בהקשותו את ערפו על דבר קטן כזה?
אם תאמר כי הוא לא ידע שהצורר הזה יקח נקמתו מכל היהודים, תשובתך בצדך כי גם אחרי שידע פתשגן כתב הדת להשמיד כל היהודים, לא קם ולא זע ממנו (אסתר ה׳:ט׳). ודוק שלא נזכרה פה כריעה והשתחויה, אלא רק לקום מפניו שהוא רק דרך מוסר, ואף דבר קל כזה לא רצה מרדכי לעשות בזמן שראה השעה משחקת להמן ומדת הדין מתוחה על ישראל, ואיך נוכל למצוא לו התנצלות? והנה הכתוב עצמו גלה לנו הטעם למה לא רצה לכרוע שנאמר: כי הגיד להם אשר הוא יהודי, שמענו מזה שרק מפני יהדותו לא כרע להמן, ולא מפני שנאה קדומה או מטעם אחר. ולפי שאין בשרשי דתנו ואמונתנו מה שיאסור ההשתחויה לבן אדם, הוכרחנו לומר כי המתנהג כן לא ירד אל עומק תכלית כונת התורה, ולכן ישים העקר טפל והטפל עקר
Mordechai had no excuse not to bow per the king's command. If it was because Haman donned an idol, that does not appear explicitly in the narrative. And the verse states that they were bowing to Haman and not to an idol. And so it is clear that whoever explains it this way (idol) is finding an excuse for Mordechai. And to explain the failure to bow due to the fact that Haman was Mordechai's prior slave - again this has no explicit support in the story. Moreover, there is no excuse not to listen to a king's command while in exile and under his jurisdiction. The law of the land is the law. And if it is because he did not want to bow to a man, this is his error in piety and not forbidden to do ... (he brings a long list of pious biblical people who bowed to others) ... why would Mordechai be more 'pious' than them? And if you explain that Mordechai felt that Haman would not notice - as is true until the King's servants brought the matter to Haman - why did Mordechai refuse to bow even after he knew Haman knew? Why would Mordechai gravely endanger himself and the Jews by being stubborn in his matter? And if you say that Mordechai did not know that Haman would punish the Jews over this, the refutation to this approach is written nearby - for even after Mordechai knew that a decree to annihilate the Jews had issued he refused to even perform a light matter such as rising or standing before Haman (such things are customary) at a time when the hour favored Haman and (God's) judgment was outstretched against Israel?! How is it possible to excuse Mordechai's behavior? The narrative tells us why he did not bow - because he was a Jew (and not because of any prior enmity or another reason). But because there is no prohibition in our religion against bowing to a man, one who accustoms himself in this way has not probed the depths of Torah and has made the unimportant into the important and vice-versa.

If one is tempted to say that R' Reggio isn't representative of the mainstream, here is a similar Midrash Tanchuma on Vayechi:

וְהַנָּבִיא צוֹוֵחַ, לֵךְ עַמִּי בֹּא בַחֲדָרֶיךָ וְגוֹ' (ישעיה כו, כ). אָמַר הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא, אֲנִי אָמַרְתִּי לָכֶם שֶׁתִּהְיוּ מַטְמִינִים עַצְמְכֶם וְתִתְּנוּ מָקוֹם לַשָּׁעָה. נָבוֹת לֹא נָתַן מָקוֹם לַשָּׁעָה, לְכָךְ כְּתִיב בֵּהּ, כִּי סֻקַּל נָבוֹת וַיָּמֶֹת (מלכים א רא, טו). מָרְדְּכַי עָמַד כְּנֶגֶד הַשָּׁעָה, וְהָיָה לוֹ לְהַחֲנִיף לָרָשָׁע. וּלְפִי שֶׁעָמַד כְּנֶגֶד הָמָן הָרָשָׁע קִמְעָא, כְּבָר הָיוּ יִשְׂרָאֵל כָּלִים מִן הָעוֹלָם.
The prophet cried out: Come, my people, enter thou into thy chambers … hide thyself for a little moment (Isa. 26:20). The Holy One, blessed be He, had declared: I counsel you to restrain yourselves and to surrender to the conditions that prevail at the moment. Naboth would not temporize (when Ahab demanded his land), and so it is written about him: Naboth is stoned, and is dead (I Kings 21:14). Mordecai likewise refused to temporize. He should have flattered the wicked man. Indeed, Israel was almost obliterated from the earth because he antagonized Haman.
דָּוִד בָּרַח וַיִּמָּלֵט מִפְּנֵי שָׁאוּל, וְכֵן בָּרַח מִפְּנֵי אַבְשָׁלוֹם בְנוֹ. וְכֵן מֹשֶׁה, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: וַיִּבְרַח מֹשֶׁה מִפְּנֵי פַרְעֹה (שמות ב, טו). וְכֵן יַעֲקֹב בָּרַח מִפְּנֵי עֵשָׂו, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: וַיִּבְרַח יַעֲקֹב שְׂדֵה אֲרָם (הושע יב, יג). וְאַף אֲבוֹת הָעוֹלָם נָתְנוּ מָקוֹם לַשָּׁעָה וְהֶחֱנִיפוּ לְמִי שֶׁהַשָּׁעָה בְיָדוֹ. אַבְרָהָם נִטְפַּל בְּשָׂרָה, לְמַעַן יִיטַב לִי בַעֲבוּרֵךְ. יִצְחָק הֶחֱנִיף לְעֵשָׂו, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: וַיֶּאֱהַב יִצְחָק אֶת עֵשָׂו. וְאַף כָּאן יַעֲקֹב קָרָא לִבְנוֹ לְיוֹסֵף,
On the other hand, David fled and escaped from Saul, and he also fled from Absalom. Moses did likewise, as it is said: He fled from the face of Pharaoh (Exod. 2:15). Similarly, Jacob fled from Esau, as it is said: And Jacob fled into the field of Aram (Hos. 12:13). Even the patriarchs temporized and flattered the one in power at the moment. Abraham relied upon Sarah: That it be well with me for thy sake (Gen. 12:13). Isaac demeaned himself before Esau, as is said: Now Isaac loved Esau (ibid. 25:28). Similarly ,in this instance Jacob called his son Joseph.

The Megillah then famously goes on to say that Mordechai urged Esther to take steps to save the Jews. And that if she did not, the Jews would be rescued anyway (Esther 4:14):

כִּ֣י אִם־הַחֲרֵ֣שׁ תַּחֲרִ֘ישִׁי֮ בָּעֵ֣ת הַזֹּאת֒ רֶ֣וַח וְהַצָּלָ֞ה יַעֲמ֤וֹד לַיְּהוּדִים֙ מִמָּק֣וֹם אַחֵ֔ר וְאַ֥תְּ וּבֵית־אָבִ֖יךְ תֹּאבֵ֑דוּ וּמִ֣י יוֹדֵ֔עַ אִם־לְעֵ֣ת כָּזֹ֔את הִגַּ֖עַתְּ לַמַּלְכֽוּת׃
On the contrary, if you keep silent in this crisis, relief and deliverance will come to the Jews from another quarter, while you and your father’s house will perish. And who knows, perhaps you have attained to royal position for just such a crisis.”

Why was Mordechai certain the Jews would be saved after he poked the bear (it was his 'refusal to temporize' that caused the danger in the first place)? How ironic! His refusal to acknowledge mortal danger requires him to urge Esther to place her own life in jeopardy! Perhaps, notwithstanding his error, he knew that God would never allow all of the Jews to be destroyed. Or maybe he continued to believe that his actions were justified throughout and thus God would rescue them? A bit of both?

Who is R' Y"SH MIGIIV? Yashar? Where is this quote taken from?

https://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Esther/3/2#e0n6

Worth noting that Yashar was pretty far from being a traditional rabbi. As noted on his wikipedia entry, his view of Mordechai was "violently criticized by [Moses Mendelssohn]".

Mendelssohn was ama famous renegade. Being criticized by such a person doesn't mean anything

Nonetheless, Joel K's summary of him is obviously true. His proof from Moses Mendelssohn is just a קל וחומר. (Unless you can find cases of his being praised by traditional rabbis.)

What the exact reference to the Tanchuma? Should be included.

@ClintEastwood "Being criticized by such a person doesn't mean anything" it definitely means something, just not the same thing to all. And for what its worth, many of the aspersions cast upon Mendelssohn's legacy are not necessarily rooted in truth. See here: https://www.hakirah.org/Vol%206%20Zelcer.pdf

"Why was Mordechai certain the Jews would be saved" This could stand alone as question without even roping in Mordekhai's allegedly erroneous/complicit action... either way, +1 for interesting question

@Deuteronomy I actually think that Mordechai's error or not error is completely irrelevant.

@MichoelR unless I misunderstand you, I'm pretty sure I just suggested that might be a possibility ;)

"if his rash and precipitous act caused the mess in the first place" - please be careful to be respectful in your choice of vocabulary when describing a tzaddik

By the way, I've always wondered if the king had really commanded his servants to bow to Haman, or if that was just something that the verse says they assumed. Maybe all he actually did was, as it says, "raise him up above the other officials". Maybe Haman couldn't simply complain to the king, because the king didn't care about people bowing to anyone but him!

See the Megilas S'tarim from the Nesivos on the verse that Mordechai would not bend nor bow. He mostly agrees with your premise, but:

מרדכי לא יכרע ולא ישתחוה. קשה הדבר שנכתב בלשון עתיד שהיה לו לכתוב
ומרדכי לא כרע ולא השתחוה. לכן נראה כי באמת מה שמרדכי לא השתחוה ואיקני'
בי' בהמן עד שרצה לכלות ישראל הי' כמעט חטא דהא אמרו במגיל' אמרה כנסת
ישראל חזי מה עשה לי יהודי דלא קטלי דוד לשמעי דנפיק מיניה מרדכי וכו'
הרי חשבו בש"ס לגנות על שלא השתחוה. והדבר קשה שמרדכי הצדיק יעשה כזאת.
אך הרמב"ן בהקדמתו לאיוב כתב שכשהצדיק עושה דבר שהוא נגד הד"ת בוודאי
נסתלק ממנו הבחירה והנה בפ' בשלח כתב רש"י על הקרא דאז ישיר שעלה בלבו
שישיר וכן כאן כוונת הכתוב שמרדכי לא עלה בלבי שיכרע היות שנסתלק ממנו
הבחירה:
"Mordechai would not bend nor bow" ... In truth, that which Mordechai
would not bow, and thus riled up Haman until he wanted to destroy
Israel - it is almost a sin!... It is hard to understand that
Mordechai the Tzaddik would do something like this. But the Ramban
says... that when a tzaddik does something against the Torah, you may
be certain that free choice was taken from him... [that is why the
future tense (יכרע, ישתחוה) is used here:] It never even occurred to him to bend or
bow.

In other words, this is a similar case to what Chazal say in the fifth perek of Gittin happened to Rabban Yochanan ben Zakkai when he spoke to Vespasian; "מֵשִׁיב חֲכָמִים אָחוֹר וְדַעְתָּם יְסַכֵּל" - "[Hashem] turns wise men backward and makes their knowledge foolish": Sometimes Hashem wants a thing to happen in a certain way, and causes our sages to make even obvious mistakes so that it will happen.
If you want to learn that Mordechai made a mistake - and most Torah-true opinions do not agree with that at all - this is the way to approach it. Mordechai remains completely innocent here.
However you approach that question, I don't see that any of it has to do with Esther, or Mordechai's words to her. Of course Hashem is not going to allow Israel to be destroyed, whether or not someone made a huge mistake. Hashem runs the world, not fools or villains. Remember that Chazal describe the whole Purim incident as a huge step forward for our nation in its relationship with Hashem, קִיְּמוּ וְקִבְּלוּ הַיְּהוּדִים — קִיְּימוּ מַה שֶּׁקִּיבְּלוּ כְּבָר: Here they finally accepted the Torah wholeheartedly (Shabbos 88a)

Interesting approach +1 Can you please elaborate on the idea of free-will being withheld from the righteous? Perhaps citing the Ramban directly?

Yeah, I caught all that already... I thought that perhaps you could beef up your answer and make it even stronger by bringing down the relevant language from the haqdama and elaborate on the concept a bit. Just a suggestion :)

I couldn't find the Ramban's hakdamah on Sefaria to quote, so I took the easy way out...

No worries... when I have some time I'll try to track down the relevant verbiage https://www.kolhalashon.com/PDF/Shiurim/33339/33339161_00019699.pdf

Was thinking about this idea a bit: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152453/behirah-the-sadiq

Fascinating idea.
